# How to find the angle between 2 pairs of points?

Tags: math, rotation, multi-touch, angle

I am doing some multi-touch support that allow 2 fingers to rotate a photos. There are four points: 2 for previous fingers and 2 for current finger positions.

I calculated a new point by subtract the 2 previous fingers, and the second new point was calculate by subtracting the other 2 current finger.

Then, I calculate the angle like this:

radian1 = atan ( p1.y / p1.x );
radian2 = atan ( p2.y / p2.x );

I subtract radian2 and radian1 to get the final angle.

The problem is I can rotate the image beautifully but sometime if I rotate to certain position the photo got flipped e.g. a photo supposed in 270 but it flipped and appeared in 90 degree.

This is the javascript I have written according to the reply below:

```
 var x1 = this.previousMousePoint.x * this.previousMousePoint2.x + this.previousMousePoint.y * this.previousMousePoint2.y;
var y1 = this.previousMousePoint.x * this.previousMousePoint2.y - this.previousMousePoint.y * this.previousMousePoint2.x;

var x2 = center.x * point.x + center.y * point.y;
var y2 = center.x * point.y - center.y * point.x;

var radian1 = Math.atan(y1 / x1);
var radian2 = Math.atan(y2 / x2);

this.anchor.matrix = this.anchor.matrix.rotate(radian2-radian1, pivot);
```

Is looking ok. but it's kind of slow when i try to rotate an image

Comment: Take a look at this wikipedia link, which will definitely help you. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean way to do this is use angle-subtraction formulas to get values proportional to the sine and cosine of the difference angle, and use atan() only once:

```
relevant formulas:
  cos(a2 - a1) = cos(a1)*cos(a2) + sin(a1)*sin(a2)
  sin(a2 - a1) = cos(a1)*sin(a2) - sin(a1)*cos(a2)

  p1.x = cos(a1) * len(p1)
  p1.y = sin(a1) * len(p1)

  p2.x = cos(a2) * len(p2)
  p2.y = sin(a2) * len(p2)

-> angle-subtraction: compute values proportional to sin and cos of (a2 - a1)
  c12 =  p1.x*p2.x + p1.y*p2.y   [ = len(p1)*len(p2) * cos(a2 - a1)  ]
  s12 =  p1.x*p2.y - p1.y*p2.x   [ = len(p1)*len(p2) * sin(a2 - a1)  ]

-> final result:  find resulting difference angle a12 [ = a2 - a1  ]
  a12 = atan(s12 / c12)
or (if you want a full 360-degree range):
  a12 = atan2(s12, c12)
```

Also, if you want to rotate an image with the result, you may not need to convert `(c12,s12)` to an angle, anyway:  ultimately, your image rotator will use a matrix with the sines and cosines of the resulting rotation angle.  By [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_vector) `(c12,s12)`, you will end up with `(cos(a12), sin(a12))`, which you may be able to use more directly.

Answer (score 0):

Arc tan maps between 0 and pi. 270 corresponds to 3/2 * pi and will fold over to pi. May I suggest that you incrementally find the angle using the positions of the fingers instead of just starting and the ending positions.

Even if you decide not to actually rotate the figure (to reduce computation), you can still display a tilted line / box / number to indicate the tilt that the software has registered.